# View all initialized broadcast receiver from all the installed application

Tags: android, performance, android-intent, android-fragments, android-activity

I have 3 questions to ask:-

`1)` I would like to list all the apps which are requested for `SMS broadcast receiver` in the `manifest file.` Is that possible?

`2)` Is it possible to block all the third party `SMS broadcast receiver`. Other than the `default SMS App`?

`3)` If a user received a link in the SMS, when the link is pressed. By default, `browser` will be opened and it will be taken to the link provided. Is it possible to stop the browser intent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to list all the apps which are requested for SMS broadcast receiver in the manifest file. Is that possible?

Use [`PackageManager` and `queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) to find who would respond to your desired SMS-related broadcast.

> Is it possible to block all the third party SMS broadcast receiver. Other than the default SMS App?

No.

> If a user received a link in the SMS, when the link is pressed. By default, browser will be opened and it will be taken to the link provided. Is it possible to stop the browser intent?

You are welcome to write your own SMS client that has this "feature". You cannot affect this behavior in other apps.